# What Values of Variables x and y Will Produce Incorrect Results When Testing for Overflow After Subtraction of x-y in the Following Program?

Tags: c, integer-overflow, twos-complement

The problem I have is concerning practice problem (2.32 - pg.94) from Computer Systems: A Programmers Perspective third edition by Randal Bryant and David O'Hallaron.

The problem is as follows:

> You are assigned the task of writing code for a function tsub_ok, with arguments `x` and `y`, that will return 1 if computing `x-y` does not cause overflow. For what values of `x` and `y` will this function give incorrect results?

The authors say that the function will give "correct values, except when `y` is `TMin`," but when I experiment with the value `TMin` for `y` it seems to work fine.

The `tsub_ok` function is as follows:

```
/* Determine whether arguments can be subtracted without overflow */

int tsub_ok(int x, int y)
{
    return tadd_ok(x, -y);
}
```

The `tadd_ok` function is as follows:

```
/* Determine whether arguments can be added without overflow */

int tadd_ok(int x, int y) 
{
     int sum = x+y;
     int neg_over = x < 0 && y < 0 && sum >= 0;
     int pos_over = x >= 0 && y >= 0 && sum < 0;
     return !neg_over && !pos_over;
}
```

Continuing on with the solution explained by the authors in regards to the functions, "we will have `-y` in the `tsub_ok` function in the `tadd_ok` function call also equal to `TMin`. So, the call to function `tadd_ok` will indicate overflow when `x` is negative and no overflow when `x` is nonnegative. In fact, the opposite is true: `tsub_ok(x, TMin)` should yield 0 when `x` is negative and 1 when it is nonnegative."

I tested these functions with a value of `TMin` for `y`, and negative and nonnegative values for `x`. The functions seem to work correctly for these values. The `tadd_ok` function indicates negative overflow when `x` is negative with the `tsub_ok` function returning 0. The `tadd_ok` function indicates no overflow when `x` is nonnegative with the `tsub_ok` function returning 1. Therefore, the functions seem to be working as intended even with `TMin` for `y` and negative and nonnegative values for `x`. So, I am confused how the results are incorrect.

Any help will be much appreciated thank you all in advance.

Comment: If `x+y` overflows, then the behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard. Does the book assert that, in the C implementation(s) to be used, that `int` arithmetic uses two’s complement and wraps modulo 2^w, where w is the number of bits in the `int` type?

Comment: Presumably `TMin` is the minimum value for the type T, and T is `int`. When asking a question based on some external source, you should give all the context, such as definitions of symbols they use.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As far as I can tell C uses two's complement arithmetic when the sum of two numbers overflows for that int type. Although the book says it's not always the case that two's complement arithmetic is used with signed int values

Comment: C 2018 6.5 5 says “If an *exceptional condition* occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined.” This means that if the mathematical result of an `int` arithmetic expression is not representable in the `int` type, the C standard does not define the behavior. (For unsigned types, the C standard defines the arithmetic to wrap, so there is never an unrepresentable result. No such definition is made for signed integer arithmetic.)

Comment: Some C implementations may define what happens when `int` arithmetic overflows. The C standard does not require them to. If the book does not say that wrapping arithmetic is used for this problem, then it is defective.

Comment: @EricPostpischilThank you for the responses. I think the problem assumes two's complement wrapping arithmetic as you described earlier with sum mod 2^w. Not taking into account the undefined behavior of c in order to teach two's complement arithmetic. However, with exception of tsub_ok(-2^31, -2^31), as you described below in your answer, I don't understand why TMin for y with a positive or negative x value produces incorrect results because It doesn't when I experiment with the functions in C for myself. I'm not sure why the authors say this.

Comment: If x is negative and y is 'Tmax', you will get overflow. If x is less than -1 and y is Tmax - 1, you'll get overflow.  If x is positive or zero and y is Tmin (assuming two's complement arithmetic — and C23 does assume that), you'll get an overflow.  If x is bigger than 1 and y is Tmin + 1, you'll get an overflow.  Etc.  If the operands have the same sign, you'll always be OK.  If they have different signs and big enough magnitude, you're vulnerable to overflow.  Indeed,  if x and y have opposite signs or one is zero and |x| + |y| > Tmax, you will get overflow.

Comment: @ChicoTabi: Either the book is wrong or you have not presented enough of the text to see the full context. As stated before, when asking a question based on some external source, you should give all the context. That includes prior sentences that establish context.

Comment: Look up the `<stdckdint.h>` and the `ckd_add()`, `ckd_sub()`, `ckd_mul()` macros in C23 (N3054 p314 — https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3054.pdf).  Integer dvision by zero is not allowed (and is one of the few reasons you might get a SIGFPE — floating point exception— in modern systems); division by any other value never overflows.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Based on the functions, do you see any other values for x and y that will cause the tsub_ok function to return incorrect results (With the exception of tsub_ok(-2^32, -2^32))? tsub_ok should return 1 when no overflow occurs or 0 if overflow occurs. I'm assuming incorrect results means the opposite occurs. 1 WITH overflow, and 0 without overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the case when `int` is 32-bit two’s complement, `int` arithmetic is defined to wrap modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, and `tsub_ok` is called with `tsub_ok(-2147483648, -2147483648)`.

Then `tsub_ok` calls `tadd_ok(-2147483648, - -2147483648)`. `- -2147483648` wraps (2,147,483,648 is not representable in `int`; the maximum representable value is 2,147,483,647) to −2,147,483,648. So `tadd_ok` is effectively called with `tadd_ok(-2147483648, -2147483648)`.

Then `tadd_ok` computes `sum = -2147483648 + -2147483648`, which wraps and sets `sum` to 0.

Then, in `int neg_over = x < 0 && y < 0 && sum >= 0;`, `x` is less than zero, `y` is less than zero, and `sum` is greater than or equal to 0, so `neg_over` is set to 1.

Then `return !neg_over && !pos_over;` causes `tadd_ok` to return 0, and `tsub_ok` returns 0 too.

However, this is an incorrect result. Subtracting −2,147,483,648 from −2,147,483,648 yields 0 with no overflow. A correctly working `tsub_ok` would return 1, to indicate the subtraction is okay.

Therefore `tsub_ok` is defective.

Answer (score 0):

2's complement range for int will have a larger negative than positive, so if it is 32 bits the valid range for any int will be [-2147483648, 2147483647].

When taking the negative of the max negative value (TMin), it will have no equivalent positive value to represent and will rollover to being the exact same value started with (i.e. `-TMin` will still result in `-2147483648` instead of `2147483648`).
So when you pass -Tmin into tadd_ok, the incorrect check will be used because pos_over will never be high since y < 0, and neg_over will be used when x<0 - this is the incorrect behavior described.

y=TMin, x < 0 *should* result in sum > 0 and no rollover (neg_over=false, pos_over=false) however since -Tmin==Tmin, it incorrectly results in neg_over=true

y=Tmin, x > 0 *should* result in sum > 0 but rollover causes that to fail, so pos_over should be true. Since -Tmin==Tmin, it incorrectly results in pos_over=false